# iOS onclick not firing

Tags: javascript

I want to know when a user clicks on my textarea.

Using the following code:

```
document.getElementById("boxtextarea").onclick = function (e) {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

Works fine in all browsers except for safari on iOS.

Any ideas how to capture when a user enters / leaves the textarea?

Comment: [`ontouchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart). [More on touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events). But if you are talking about textarea, you should use `focus` and `blur`.

Comment: Nothing is firing still :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8fo8z5h6/1/

Comment: do you have any :hover css bind to your textarea ?

Comment: Dont have a :hover. But maybe its cause my textarea is inside of an iframe? Im running the code from within that iframe

Comment: Strange thing is that onkeyup works from inside my iframe..